# What is the difference between using a method and a property?

Tags: ios, properties, readonly

I am studying the source code for "The Elements" sample app and I see that in [AtomicElement.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Listings/Classes_AtomicElement_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007419-Classes_AtomicElement_h-DontLinkElementID_13) there are four properties declared as readonly:

```
@property (readonly) UIImage *stateImageForAtomicElementTileView;
@property (readonly) UIImage *flipperImageForAtomicElementNavigationItem;
@property (readonly) UIImage *stateImageForAtomicElementView;
@property (readonly) CGPoint positionForElement;
```

In the implementation file, they look like

```
- (UIImage *)stateImageForAtomicElementTileView {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_37.png",state]];
}
```

Can you please elaborate on the reasons to do that? Why not use something like

```
- (UIImage*) stateImageForAtomicElementTileView;
```

in the header file, and then access it like `[element stateImageForAtomicElementTileView];` instead of `element.stateImageForAtomicElementTileView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a technical reason to choose one idiom over the other, they can both be used in the same way. It's more a matter of semantics.

A class has both data and can perform operations (usually on said data). I think you should look at using a property, and having the `.` access instead of `[ ]` more as a way of documenting the purpose of the `stateImageForAtomicElementTileView`.

It's an image that's part of the class (the fact is't being generated on the fly from a resource should be seen as an implementation detail)

Comment: Good, I'm happy with that answer :)